# Flutter divider widget not appearing

Tags: flutter

I'm currently learning how to build apps using the Flutter SDK and Android Studio. My problem is that I need to add a Divider widget between the 'Administrative' text and the rest of the Card but as you can see in the screenshot below, the divider isn't showing up. I've tried changing the size (In which case the space between the two texts just increases) and I've tried setting the color to see if it was defaulting to transparent on my phone. Nothing works!

Here's my code for the Card Widget State:

```
class BBSCardState extends State<BBSCard>{
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 16.0, bottom: 16.0, left: 12.0, right: 12.0),
      child: new Card(
        child: new Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            new Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: <Widget>[
                new Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 22.0, bottom: 8.0),
                  child: new Text("Administrative", style: new TextStyle(color: new Color.fromARGB(255, 117, 117, 117), fontSize: 32.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                ),
                new Divider(),
                new Text("text")
              ],
            ),
          ],
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        )
      )
    );
  }
}
```

And here's the screenshot of what the card looks like:

[image: The divider does not appear between the two texts]

**Also:**
Is there any way to increase the size of the actual line from the Divider? (Not just the spacing)

Thanks!

Answer (score 59, accepted):

You could remove `Row`, then `Column` would take all available space  and `Divider` would have width.

```dart
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return new Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
        top: 16.0, bottom: 16.0, left: 12.0, right: 12.0),
    child: new Card(
      child: new Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: <Widget>[
          new Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 22.0, bottom: 8.0),
            child: new Text("Administrative",
                style: new TextStyle(
                    color: new Color.fromARGB(255, 117, 117, 117),
                    fontSize: 32.0,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
          ),
          new Divider(
            color: Colors.red,
          ),
          new Text("text")
        ],
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

[image: Result]

To make custom divider you could check implementation of `Divider` and adjust it. E.g. replace `Divider` with

```dart
new SizedBox(
  height: 10.0,
  child: new Center(
    child: new Container(
      margin: new EdgeInsetsDirectional.only(start: 1.0, end: 1.0),
      height: 5.0,
      color: Colors.red,
    ),
  ),
)
```

[image: CustomDivider]

Comment: Oh, I see! Thanks, I'm very new to dart and am coming straight from Android. Some of these concepts aren't too easy for me to grasp.

Comment: If you needed the row widget there, another way to provide the column width for the Divider class would be to wrap the Column Widget with something like Expanded - then your code would work.

Answer (score 18):

it was happening to me but I found out that this property solves it: `thickness`

```
 child: Divider(
                color: Colors.teal.shade100,
                thickness: 1.0,
              ),
```

Answer (score 14):

I had the same issue, but by putting my **Divider** inside an **Expanded** Widget fixed my problem.

```
Row(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
  children: <Widget>[
    Expanded(
      child: Divider(
        thickness: 1,
        color: Color(0xff818181),
      ),
    ),
    SizedBox(width: 10),
    Text(
      'Login using Social Media',
      style: TextStyle(color: Color(0xff818181), fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
    ),
    SizedBox(width: 10),
    Expanded(
      child: Divider(
        thickness: 1,
        color: Color(0xff818181),
      ),
    ),
  ],
),
```

Answer (score 10):

```
Container(
           decoration: BoxDecoration(
             border: Border(
               bottom: BorderSide(color: Colors.lightGreen,width: 3.0),
             ),
           ),
         )
```

Instead of using divider you can use a customized container...

Answer (score 10):

In `Column`, use `Divider()` and in `Row`, use `VerticalDivider()`

Answer (score 2):

```
 Container(
                    width: 200,
                    child: Divider(
                      thickness: 10,
                      color: Colors.red,
                    ),
                  ),

or 
 Expanded(
                    child: Divider(
                      thickness: 10,
                      color: Colors.red,
                    ),
                  ),
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to draw line for the Widget Views, Try using the BoxDecoration as like in below example

```
child: new Container(
  decoration: new BoxDecoration(
   border: Border(
    top: BorderSide(width: 1.0, color: Colors.grey),
    left: BorderSide(width: 1.0, color: Colors.grey),
    right: BorderSide(width: 1.0, color: Colors.grey),
    bottom: BorderSide(width: 1.0, color: Colors.grey),),
 );

 child: new Row( 
         ....
 ),
)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use it inside row like you have multiple widgets to show inside row and also a divider then you can use Sizedbox with height and width . pasting code

```
 SizedBox(
            width: 60,
            height: 30,
            child: Divider(
              height: 20,

              color: defaultColor,
              thickness: 5,
            ),
          ),
```

Answer (score 0):

**Horizontal divider**

```
Container(
  width: double.infinity,
  height: 2, // Thickness
  color: Colors.grey,
)
```

**Vertical divider**

```dart
Container(
  width: 2, // Thickness
  height: double.infinity,
  color: Colors.grey,
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Recently I have to archive divider which have circular corner. but if I'm using container with border side it's not give accurate output. So you can use this code if you want circular corner.

```
ClipRRect(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6.33.r),
                  child: Container(
                    width: 100.w,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      border: Border(
                        bottom: BorderSide(
                            color: Color.fromRGBO(196, 196, 196, 0.6),
                            width: 5.0.w),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried with expanded widget but not worked. But only this way it works for me

```
SizedBox(
        height: 50,
        child: VerticalDivider(
          thickness: 3,
          width: 4,
          indent: 0,
          color: ColorConstants.silverColor,
        ),
      ),
```

This way also worked for me, when I wrapped parent (Row) with IntrinsicHeight

```
IntrinsicHeight(
  child: Row(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
    children: const [       
      Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15.0),
        child: VerticalDivider(
          thickness: 3,
          width: 4,
          indent: 0,
          color: ColorConstants.silverColor,
        ),
      ),
      HighTrendWidget(
        trendValue: 'HIGH',
        trendDifference: '1743.88',
      )
    ],
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

The code below worked for me:

```
PreferredSize(
   preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(1),
   child: Container(
      color: Colors.grey,
      height: 1,
   ),
),
```

Note that PreferredSize is a Widget

Answer (score 0):

Delete this line: import: dart:js_util;

I had a same problem. But it had another reason. It was because of: import: dart:js_util;
After removing this line, my issue was resolved. While I'm uncertain about the specific impact of this library on the Divider, it appears that it was preventing the Divider from being displayed.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
Card (
   child: Column ( 
      children: [ 
       Text("Text"), 
       SizedBox( 
          width: 100.00, 
          child: Divider( color: Colors.grey, thickness: 1.0),),
      ],
   )
),
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right:20),
            child:Divider(
              color: Color(0xfff8a9c5),
              thickness: 2,


            ),
      ),
```

Answer (score -1):

Just Use this function for wherever you want

```
 Divider verticalDivider() {
   return Divider(
      height: 2,
      color: Colors.greenAccent,
    );
  }
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30457935)

Answer (score -1):

Add the thickness:

```
Divider(
   thickness: 1,
   color: Colors.teal.shade100,
)
```

Answer (score -1):

Just adding the thickness parameter to 1 or above will solve the issue.

Working sample:

```
const Divider(
     height: 1,
     thickness: 1),
```